# chkconfig in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, services

I using Ubuntu 12.04.1
From Red Hat I know command chkconfig which in very easy way for set startup mode of services.
In same easy way as it is in Windows (services.msc).
Unfortunately in Ubuntu this utility don't exists...
I admitted that services which I just stopped with:

```
service service-name stop
```

don't wake up after reboot... But this is inappropriate way to manage services' startup mode comparing to most platforms.
Have we some more standard way?

Comment: you are telling that in Ubuntu `chkconfig` is not available right?

Comment: I just supposed that fact that it not installed point to incompatibility of this tool with Ubuntu. I supposed that maybe init.d archetecture of Ubuntu different from other distributions... But if you say that it is compatible, so it make me happy. Sure, I will install this tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is ubuntu only

And I am using `Ubuntu 12.04`

[image]

If it is not there then try this command to install

> root@localhost:~# apt-get install chkconfig

Comment: Wonderful, as I said I just was worried that it is incompatible. But now after you said that Ubuntu working fine with it, I installed it. I really happy that this tool availible in Ubuntu :) Thanx for response.

Comment: @Rodnower sometimes it happens...:-) thank you....

Answer (score 1):

This post at AskUbuntu is quite complete description of starting, stopping and configuring services:
[What's the recommended way to enable / disable services?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19320/whats-the-recommended-way-to-enable-disable-services)

Comment: Hi, wecome to Superuser. Here, it's usual to summarize helpful details from an external source instead of just linking it.

Comment: Ah, OK. Thanks for clarifying. Just learning to get around in this community.

Answer (score 0):

Since Ubuntu 12.10 abandoned chkconfig, https://askubuntu.com/questions/221293/why-is-chkconfig-no-longer-available-in-ubuntu suggests the use of sysv-rc-conf as an alternative.